A linux application for work with simple tables
Please, recommend an application where I would create simple tables/grids/matrices with ability to paint separate cells in different colors easily, something like in the picture below. For example, by clicking on a cell to just paint it in a particular color, or by selecting some (not necessarily adjacent) cells before painting them all.

I don't need any calculation features. At the moment, I don't even need to insert a text into cells. And any row or column headers are useless for me now. I want to just paint the cells.
I tried some apps like Libreoffice Draw, but didn't find a quick way to paint multiple cells. Maybe I just missed something.
Please, suggest a linux app of this kind.

Welcome Andrey! You may find it helpful to look for what is known as a "pixel editor"; they do exactly what you desire.  I don't currently have a recommendation for you, but there should be quite a few good ones out there.  Good luck!

@EndAntisemiticHate, thanks. Your suggestion makes sense. I'll try to find a simple one, although it seems there is a lot of memory consuming and bloated Art pixel editors.

You're welcome.  You may find that pixel editors designed for programmers to be more memory efficient than ones tailored for artists.

You could use Inkscape 1.3+ and its new Shape Builder Tool to do this.
But be warned: its user interface is not really intuitive. I recommend to watch a tutorial video first, especially Shape Builder Tool use in conjunction with "isometric grids". (just use a square grid not a triangular grid )


Thanks a lot. I'll try it more carefully and in detail later.
In fact, it's so strange one can't easily manage to get a small fairly minimalistic app of this kind.
